# Theoretical and computational results of ODE differ a lot! Why?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

**Hello. I have a problem in that my theoretical and practical(computational)  calculations  differ a lot.  *in 1 order of magnitude actually.***

---

*Impulse I needed to jump over the saddle point in one case is approx. equals 0.16 in the other approx. 0.06*
I do not understand what is the problem.

---

**Theoretical part:**

---

I have a potential energy that is :
$$U(\theta,\phi) = \frac{1}{2}k_2(2M_0)^2cos(\theta)^2 -\frac{1}{4}k_4(2M_0)^4(sin(\theta)^4cos(\phi)^4+sin(\theta)^4sin(\phi)^4+cos(\theta)^4)$$
$k_2, k_4 >0$,$k_2>>k_4$, let $M_0 = 1/2$

Local maximum(Saddle point) is when $(\theta,\phi) = (\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{4})$. 
$$U = -\frac{1}{4}k_4 \times \frac{1}{2}    $$

Local and global minimum is when $(\theta,\phi) = (\pi/2,\pi/2)$, then pot. energy is:
  $$U = - \frac{1}{4} k_4$$

Logicaly, if I have a particle on the bottom of the potential well and know it`s energy and know the energy of the saddle point I need to go over, the kinetic energy is the difference:
$$\Delta U =  \frac{1}{8} k_4$$

As my kinetic energy is the following:
$$ T = \alpha' 4M_0^2 (\dot\theta^2 +  sin^2(\theta)\dot{\phi})^2 $$
Hence:
Impulse needed to move in the direction of coordinate $\phi$ is :
$$ \dot\phi = \sqrt { \frac{k_4}{8\alpha'}  }$$
While 
I get:
$\omega_{af} = \frac{k_4}{2\alpha'}, \gamma_{af} = \frac{\alpha}{2\alpha'} $

$$ \dot\phi = \sqrt { \frac{2\alpha'\omega_{af}}{8\alpha'}  }$$

$$ \dot\phi = 0.16$$

---

**Computational part**

---

$$ [  \ddot{\theta} ]=  [ sin(\theta)cos(\theta)\dot{\phi}^2 + \frac{k_2}{2 \alpha'}cos(\theta)sin(\theta)+   \omega_{af}^2(sin(\theta)^3cos(\theta)cos(\phi)^4+sin(\theta)^3cos(\theta)sin(\phi)^4 - cos(\theta)^3sin(\theta)) ] - [ 2 \gamma_{af} \dot{\theta}  ];$$

$$[\ddot{\phi}] = - [cot(\theta)\dot{\phi}\dot{\theta}] + [\omega_{af}^2(-sin(\theta)^2cos(\phi)^3sin(\phi) +sin(\theta)^2sin(\phi)^3cos(\phi)) ] - [2\gamma_{af} \dot{\phi}  - \frac{1}{2}  j  ]. $$

here is the matlab code:

```
function xDot = parallelDegreesW42_mistake_v2(t,x,~,w_af,g_af,gcurr)
k_2 = 125;
k_4 = 12.5;
alpha_stroke = 62.5;
xDot  = [x(2); ... %//= theta'

    sin(x(1)) * cos(x(1)) * ((x(4))^2) + ...
    + ( k_2 * sin( 2 * x(1) ) / ( 4 * alpha_stroke)   ) + ...
    (w_af^2) * (   ( sin(x(1)) )^3  *  cos(x(1)) * ( cos(x(3)) )^4 + ( sin(x(1)) )^3 * cos(x(1)) * ( sin(x(3)) )^4 - ( cos(x(1)) )^3 * sin(x(1))  ) + ...
    - 2 * g_af * x(2);

    x(4); ... %//= phi'

    - x(2) * x(4) * cot(x(1)) + ...
    (w_af^2) * (sin(x(1)))^2 * cos(x(3)) * sin(x(3)) *(-(cos(x(3)))^2 + (sin(x(3)))^2) + ...
    - 2 * g_af * (sin(x(1)))^2 * x(4)  + ...
    + 0.5 * gcurr];
```

and code for plotting:

```
function f = callDegrees(v_theta, v_phi,)
    %%
    %
    theta = pi/2;
    phi = (3*pi/4+pi/2)/2;
    w_af = 0.1;
    g_af = 0.01;
    gcurr = 0; % this is j in system of ODES;
    x0 = [theta,v_theta,phi,v_phi];
    tspan = 0:0.01:1000;
    options = odeset('RelTol',1e-8,'AbsTol',[1e-8 1e-8 1e-8 1e-8]);
    [t,x] = ode45('parallelDegreesW42_mistake_v2',tspan,x0, options, w_af, g_af, gcurr );
    xx1 = x(:,1);%theta
    xx2 = x(:,3);%phi

    xx3 = x(:,2);%V_theta
    xx4 = x(:,4);%V_phi

    plot(t,xx3,'--','LineWidth' ,1);
    xlabel('t');
    ylabel('phi');
```

extra remarks: 
$$w_{af} = 0.1, g_{af}=0.01,j=0$$
FINALY, 
$$ \dot\phi_{byCOMPUTER} = 0.065$$

Comment: Let's make it clear. Since variables $\phi$ and $\theta$ are both $2\pi$-periodic, I bet that it is some kind of double pendulum, but that's not important now. These equations were obtained from Lagrange principle (equations of motions are obtained through the Euler-Lagrange equations for Lagrangian). Am I right? What are you doing exactly to move the particle from one state to another?

Comment: Yes, let $\phi \in [0,2\pi], \theta \in [0,\pi] $, I am sorry, I did not write it.
This is a kind of extremely simplified simulation of a motion of a magnetic moment vector in a material.Yes, I do use Euler-Lagrange equations, and I have both kinetic and potential energy as well as extra term - dissipative force.  I get 2 differential equations after considering $\theta,\phi$ as generalized coordinates. By moving a particle/ or more precisely, a vector of magnetic moment I should use the current( it is j - in written equations, and gcurr - in matlab code).

Comment: Your question: What are you doing exactly to move the particle from one state to another?       Here I want to change initial conditions( velocity), so that the movement can go from the potential well, (particle/vector is in potential well  by the initial conditions )

Comment: So, do you introduce any control term into equations or leave them as you've obtained them from Euler-Lagrange procedure? If not, you just might have missed the basin of attraction of your desired state.

Comment: it is in my dissipative force, it has a component j (or gcurr) - it is a current. it is written in $$\ddot\phi =... \text{equation}$$

Comment: But it is still a constant over time? You know, I think that I understand what might happened. Your mentioned states were steady states in original equations, without dissipation. When you introduce dissipation they are no longer steady states, but new equilibria points appear. So it might be a reason for the difference between your computed and observed quantities.

Comment: Could you be pleased to explain more? I can not understand how dissipation can change steady states.=(

Comment: Yes, I think I can, but let's move to the chat. I still need to clarify some things.

Comment: The chat is on the bottom. But How can I go there and create a conversation?

Comment: If there's a link that suggests to move discussion to chat, just click it. It'd be great because I have few questions that might be quite lengthy.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in my calculations.
I did write that $\omega_{af} = k_4/2\alpha',...$. That is a mistake, I should have written $\omega_{af}^2 = k_4/2\alpha'$. After, I will receive the following:
$$\phi_{ini} = \sqrt {\omega_{af}^2 / 4} = \omega_{af}/2 = 0.05$$ Which sounds ok. The code was correct.

Thank you  ***Evgeny*** for helping to solve my problem. I did actually understood a bit, what have you meant by the phrase:

> Your mentioned states were steady states in original equations,
>   without dissipation. When you introduce dissipation they are no longer
>   steady states, but new equilibria points appear.

Comment: Nevertheless I have a new task. I want to find an impulse gcurr, which will help me to go over the potential well without the initial velocity. I am looking for how to evaluate the value of an impulse. Any suggestions how to do this? I am planning to use the magnitude of an impulse as a gauss function. $gcurr(constant) \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}t_{impulse}} exp(-(t/t_{impulse})^2)$